# Issue with modifying a Keras class to include call function

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I want to train a VAE that had a huge dataset and decided to use a VAE [code](http://%20%20I%20had%20to%20train%20a%20VAE%20that%20had%20a%20huge%20dataset%20and%20decided%20to%20use%20a%20VAE%20code%20made%20for%20fashion%20MNIST%20and%20popular%20modifications%20for%20batch%20loading%20using%20filenames%20that%20I%20found%20on%20github.%20%20But%20the%20way%20the%20VAE%20class%20is%20written%20it%20does%20not%20have%20a%20call%20function%20which%20should%20be%20there%20according%20to%20keras%20documentation) made for fashion MNIST and popular modifications for [batch-loading](https://towardsdatascience.com/variational-autoencoders-vaes-for-dummies-step-by-step-tutorial-69e6d1c9d8e9) using filenames that I found on github. My research collab notebook is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i0atFcJh3vRCM6Cm8qnfsaCwR3GYRYDB?usp=sharing) and a sample section of [dataset](https://gofile.io/d/F2sna4).

But the way the VAE class is written it does not have a call function which should be there according to keras [documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model/). I am getting the error **NotImplementedError: When subclassing the `Model` class, you should implement a `call` method.**

```
class VAE(tf.keras.Model):
"""a basic vae class for tensorflow
Extends:
    tf.keras.Model
"""

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(VAE, self).__init__()
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    self.enc = tf.keras.Sequential(self.enc)
    self.dec = tf.keras.Sequential(self.dec)

def encode(self, x):
    mu, sigma = tf.split(self.enc(x), num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
    return ds.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=sigma)

def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):
    eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
    return eps * tf.exp(logvar * 0.5) + mean

def reconstruct(self, x):
    mu, _ = tf.split(self.enc(x), num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
    return self.decode(mu)

def decode(self, z):
    return self.dec(z)

def compute_loss(self, x):

    q_z = self.encode(x)
    z = q_z.sample()
    x_recon = self.decode(z)
    p_z = ds.MultivariateNormalDiag(
      loc=[0.] * z.shape[-1], scale_diag=[1.] * z.shape[-1]
      )
    kl_div = ds.kl_divergence(q_z, p_z)
    latent_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(kl_div, 0))
    recon_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(x - x_recon), axis=0))

    return recon_loss, latent_loss

def compute_gradients(self, x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = self.compute_loss(x)
    return tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)

@tf.function
def train(self, train_x):
    gradients = self.compute_gradients(train_x)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))
```

and the encoder and decoder are defined separately and compiled as

```
N_Z = 8
filt_base = 32
DIMS = (128,128,3)

encoder = [
tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=DIMS),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=filt_base, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=filt_base, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation="relu", padding="same"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=filt_base*2, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=filt_base*2, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation="relu", padding="same"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=filt_base*3, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=filt_base*3, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation="relu", padding="same"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=filt_base*4, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=filt_base*4, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation="relu", padding="same"
),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=N_Z*2),
]

decoder = [
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8 * 8 * 128, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(8, 8, 128)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=filt_base*4, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME", activation="relu"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=filt_base*4, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding="SAME", activation="relu"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=filt_base*3, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME", activation="relu"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=filt_base*3, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding="SAME", activation="relu"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=filt_base*2, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME", activation="relu"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=filt_base*2, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding="SAME", activation="relu"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=filt_base, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME", activation="relu"
),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=1, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding="SAME", activation="sigmoid"
),
]

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3)

model = VAE(
  enc = encoder,
  dec = decoder,
  optimizer = optimizer,
)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer)
```

and trying to train the model using **fit_generator function**

```
num_epochs = 50
model.fit_generator(generator=my_training_batch_generator,
                                      steps_per_epoch=(num_training_samples // batch_size),
                                      epochs=num_epochs,
                                      verbose=1,
                                      validation_data=my_validation_batch_generator,
                                      validation_steps=(num_validation_samples // batch_size),
                                      use_multiprocessing=True,
                                      workers=16,
                                      max_queue_size=32)
```

I am new to machine learning and any help to resolve the issue would be appreciated. I think the issue is with the def train line in class VAE.

An optional request is if the training can be done so that I can see the reconstruction after each epoch would be appreciated. I already have a **plot_reconstruction** function in the research collab notebook for this purpose that needs to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APaul31,

Specifically in your code I suggest adding `call()` function to the VAE class:

```
def call(self, x):
    q_z = self.encode(x)
    z = q_z.sample()
    x_recon = self.decode(z)
```

I also suggest to use more standard approach to your task, especially as a beginner:

1. use  `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` for image loading. Tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images).
2. use custom `Model.train_step()` to calculate VAE losses instead of multiple functions in your VAE class. Example [here](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/).

Comment: the answer above was updated after this discussion at Github https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43173

Comment: Hi Ruslan, Thank you so much for looking into the problem in detail. I modified the main VAE class as you suggested and I think I resolved the issue with the call function. But I am having some issues with the custom file loading class. I cannot use the image_dataset_from_directory() as it loads the whole dataset and memory of collab notebook will run out. Will it be possible to have a quick look at the updated notebook? Currently I am having the error of TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: 1) please accept and upvote the original answer

2) on your memory runout issue: Instead of `image_dataset_from_directory()` try writing custom generator as `keras.utils.Sequence` subclass. in its `__getitem__()` function you can control the data loading process to ensure that only single batch gets loaded into memory. See example here: [https://medium.com/@mrgarg.rajat/training-on-large-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory-in-keras-60a974785d71]

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation, Can't upvote you :-|

Comment: This will pass )

Comment: Wow! thanks! Upvoted your answer! Can I DM you somehow for some advise?

Comment: Thx! DM is not productive - my knowledge is quite limited and I am not available 24/7. Just post a good question to SO with the right tags. If I am around - I will pick it up. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I am having the error of TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

The problem is with `fit` method, when you are passing a data generator use `fit_generator` instead of `fit`. In the collab it's calling `fit`

Also, note that you can use `flow_from_directory` method instead of `image_dataset_from_directory`  to lazily generate batches, it won't load the whole data into memory
https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method.

Comment: Hi Surj, I modified my code to include flow_from_directory functionality and it is able to load the data and starts the first epoch but it runs into new error now `ValueError: Layer sequential_1 expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>]`  Any help would be appreciated. Dataset is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Lh6891_rtws65rvEkeYMAPFHC515tEuf). Tagging Ruslan also @Ruslan S.